# What is the deeper meaning of the Exit() function in vpython.py line 18 to 22 in vpython 7.6.4

Tags: vpython

The Exit() function in module vpython.py in vpython 7.6.4 is implemented as follows and
registered with atexti:

```
def Exit():
    zero = 0.
    print('exit')
    a = 1.0/zero

import atexit
atexit.register(Exit)
```

What is the deeper meaning of this code?

Kind regards

Klaus